# Cross Platform Input Controller Not Working on Mobile Device

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity Standard Assets - Cross Platform Input Control to create Dpad as per my game requirements.

I was following this video tutorial for implementation:
[How to move character or game object in Android Top Down Unity game with UI Buttons? Easy tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smijH2fbw8s)

I have imported only Cross-Platform Input data within the project, as seen below because I won't be using other things.
[image]

To move my 2D player character, I have used this code:

```
 horizontalMove = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
 verticalMove = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
```

Plus, 4 Button Components. I've set them up this way:
[image]

After using the code shown above, I could move a player inside my Unity Editor, but I wasn't able to move my player when tested on my mobile device. It appears that for some reason I am not receiving any values for my horizontal and vertical input.

If there is anyone who could give me some guidance or point me up in solving my mobile input problem. I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Event Trigger and on each Button when being pressed use a GetButton to call a Method which will change a bool for 1 direction. Deppending of that bool the player will move, then use GetButtonUp to change back the state of that bool which will stop moving player in one direction. This is simple, there is no need to use Unity Standard Assets.

Comment: Yes, I did the same, removed Standard Assets package and using Trigger Event implemented own Dpad controller.

Comment: Great, now you just have to repeat the same process for each direction and thats about it. ;)